# Slack - change week start day for message reminder

Tags: slack

I'm using Slack reminders extensively. When reading a message I want to handle next week, I just use "Next Week" message reminder.

However, my work week starts on Sunday, where this message would pop up on Monday as the default week start day.

Is there a way to customise this?
[image]

Comment: Worse than this, if you are on Sunday and you select to "remind me next week", it sets the reminder for 8 days time. So which is it Slack? Does the week start on Sunday or Monday?

Answer (score 18):

According to slack support, there's currently no way to do it (hope it would be an option someday).

The current workaround is to use set the reminder manually, using `/remind me to xxx on Sunday`